# Haskell. Return the length of the largest sequence of required items in the list

Tags: haskell

The assignment is:

> A list and one of its elements are given. You must return the length of the largest sequence of such items in this list.The function should output the following:

```
longestSpan "aabaaaa" a 
-> 4
longestSpan [1,2,3,2,2,2] 2 
-> 3
longestSpan "Hellow" l
-> 2
```

I am trying to solve this problem as follows:

```
longestSpan lst x = longestSpan' lst x 0

longestSpan' [] _ s = s
longestSpan' (h:t) x s | x == h = 
   if (l>s) then longestSpan' (drop l t) x l 
            else longestSpan' (drop l t) x s 
   where 
   l = countX t 1 x

countX [] i x = i
countX (h:t) i x | x == h = countX (i+1) x
                 | otherwise i
```

output:

```
   parse error 
   (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

But I can not find the error no matter how I tried. Please help me fix the code.

Comment: Why do you think there is an error?

Comment: `group` could be a starting point.

Comment: output: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Comment: You're missing a `=` after `otherwise`

Comment: otherwise = i . Unfortunately, this fix did not help. A lot of mistakes came out.

Comment: @Seliverstov, take them one step at a time.   There's no magic bullet, programming is just fixing problems until there are no more problems.

Comment: there should be a line number, or some other indication of where the parse error occurs, *in the **full** error message*. please always include *full error message* in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a concise solution, see @andrew-ray's answer. If you just want to fix your code, this is easy. Your logic is good, but there are a few mistakes in the code.

Your `longestSpan` function calls an auxiliary function `longestSpan'`:

```
longestSpan:: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
longestSpan lst x = longestSpan' lst x 0
```

The new parameter `s` is the longest span found so far (`0` at the beginning). The idea is:

1. find the longest span `xxxx...` at the beginning of `lst`
2. "update" `s` if necessary.

To achieve 1., we need a `spanSize` function (your `countX`). But we don't need a extra parameter here: the size grows until the list is empty or the head is not `x`.

```
spanSize:: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
spanSize [] _ = 0
spanSize (h:t) x
    | x == h = 1 + spanSize t x
    | otherwise = 0
```

To achieve 2., we just compute the new span size `s'`, compare it to the previous one, maybe change the best span size, and continue our exploration after dropping the (possibly empty) found span:

```
longestSpan':: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int
longestSpan' [] x s = s
longestSpan' lst x s = longestSpan' (drop (l+1) lst) x s'
                           where l = spanSize lst x
                                 s' = if l>s then l else s
```

We can drop `l+1` because we know that the `l+1-th` element is not `x` (or does not exist).

A test:

```
main = do print $ longestSpan "aabaaaa" 'a'
          print $ longestSpan [1,2,3,2,2,2] 2
          print $ longestSpan "Hellow" 'l'
          print $ longestSpan "Hellow" 'w'
          print $ longestSpan "Hellow" 'z'
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

This is far less elegant than the accepted answer, but still interesting as an exercise.

---

It is possible to get the same result using a `foldl`:

```
longestSpan2:: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
longestSpan2 lst x = fst $ foldl (\(best, cur) v -> if v == x then (if cur >= best then cur+1 else best, cur+1) else (best, 0)) (0, 0) lst
```

The logic is *exactly* the same: we keep track of the `best` span and of the `current` span. At the beginning, both are `0`. If the current element is `x`, we increase `cur` and check if `best` was beaten. As soon as the current element is not `x`, `cur` is set to `0` and `best` is left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much Jferard for the beautiful, detailed and explanatory answer !!!! This is exactly what you need !! I understood where I made mistakes. I still have a lot to learn Haskell)

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using [`Data.List.group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group), which splits a list up into groups where all elements are the same:

```
group "aabaaaa"
-> ["aa", "b", "aaaa"]
```

Then, you can [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) out the ones that are wrong:

```
filter (('a' ==) . head) . group $ "aabaaaa"
-> ["aa", "aaaa"]
```

From there, [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) over the list to get the `length` of each string:

```
map length . filter (('a' ==) . head) . group $ "aabaaaa"
-> [2, 4]
```

And take the [`maximum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) element of the list:

```
maximum . map length . filter (('a' ==) . head) . group $ "aabaaaa"
-> 4
```

Which leads us quite nicely to the definition:

```
longestSpan xs a = 
    maximum . map length . filter ((a ==) . head) . group $ xs
```

As Willem points out, this will actually blow up if the target element did not occur in the list at all. This can be fixed by appending a `0` to the list of lengths just before taking the maximum.

```
longestSpan xs a =
    maximum . (0:) . map length . filter ((a ==) . head) . group $ xs
```

Just as a point of interest, though, you may actually find it more useful to flip the order of the arguments:

```
longestSpan a = maximum . (0:) . map length . filter ((a ==) . head) . group
```

Comment: It might be worth adding a `maximum . (0:) . map length ...`, to return `0` in case that `'a'` does not occur (did not dv btw).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, that's a good point. I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: What an elegant and beautiful solution for a "string" !!! Thank!

Comment: @Seliverstov: a `String` is just a list of `Char`s, indeed `type String = [Char]`, so functions that operate on a list can operate on a `String` as well.

Comment: The basic type of the function is `Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int`. This should work for all your cases; I just focused on the string example to show how to produce function compositions by working backwards from a known case.

Comment: Yes, I have already understood. Thank Andrew Ray for the detailed answer!